# Can I use prepare statement to create function and stored procedures in mysql?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, prepared-statement, stored-functions

I need to create a new function and stored procedures through the prepare and execute statement. Whether it is possible or not?

```
prepare statement from 'DELIMITER ;;
CREATE FUNCTION `db_name`.`fn_name`(Params)
RETURNS varchar(50) CHARSET utf8mb4 DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
DECLARE name varchar(50);
RETURN IFNULL(name,"");
END ;;
DELIMITER ;';
execute statement;
```

Comment: You cannot use `PREPARE` and `EXECUTE` statements to create functions or stored procedures directly.

Comment: These statements are mainly used to execute dynamic SQL queries, but they do not support defining functions or procedures.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not possible. See [SQL Syntax Permitted in Prepared Statements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-prepared-statements.html#prepared-statements-permitted) for the list of statements allowed in prepared statements. `CREATE PROCEDURE` isn't one of them.